# BigQuery TIMESTAMP TO DATETIME

Tags: google-bigquery

[Conversion rules in Google](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) say that `TIMESTAMPS` can become `DATETIME`.

The following code works to turn a `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE`.

```
SELECT CAST( DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS DATE)
```

We can get a `DATETIME` using this in Standard SQL but we lose the time in the process:

```
SELECT  CAST ( CAST( DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME )
```

How do we get a `TIMESTAMP` to become a `DATETIME` without losing the time (i.e. something like this)?

```
SELECT CAST(   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS DATETIME )
```

How do we do this in Legacy SQL and Standard SQL on BigQuery?

NOTE: We just discovered our example CAST works on Standard SQL (it appears our query system was using Legacy SQL).

Comment: What is the expected answer? I am getting  2019-06-13T08:15:22.875369 for the direct CAST( as DATETIME)

Comment: SELECT DATETIME_TRUNC( DATETIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), SECOND) as datetime . Or you can use `FORMAT_DATETIME()` also . See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_datetime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use CAST(... as DATETIME) as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ts_as_timestamp
)
SELECT ts_as_timestamp, CAST(ts_as_timestamp AS DATETIME) ts_as_datetime
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row ts_as_timestamp                 ts_as_datetime   
1   2019-06-13 19:22:42.839108 UTC  2019-06-13T19:22:42.839108
```

For Legacy SQL

```
#legacySQL
SELECT ts_as_timestamp, CAST(STRING(ts_as_timestamp) AS DATETIME) ts_as_datetime
FROM (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ts_as_timestamp)
```

with same output

Comment: And for Legacy SQL? (That's the one failing) (I just realized I put an "or" in the question - meaning a layman "or" (i.e. "and") rather than a logical "or")

Comment: @Praxiteles -  added to my answer

Comment: STRING first...aigh! I am not certain I follow why it works to turn the INT64 to a STRING works for DATETIME but to my great relief - it does work.

Comment: DATE, TIME and DATETIME in legacy has a limited support and is implemented the way it is  - you can see more about [Civil time in legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types#civil-time)